# Whats the best way to compress different type of files uploaded via multer in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, compression, multer

I'm using [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) to compress the requests to enhance the performance of my app.

What's the best way to compress different type of files uploaded via [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)?

Especially PNG/JPEG/PDF types of files.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use appropriate command line utils + `fs.exec`.
And you can easily test their compression rate just in terminal.